# Как методом `GET` получить значение `index.php`?

Tags: php

Есть условие `<? if ($page=='index') {echo 'class="active"';}` как получить значение `index` с ссылки например `blabla.ru/index.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

например, pathinfo . нужная вам часть filename

```
print_r(pathinfo('blabla.ru/index.php'));

Array
(
    [dirname] => blabla.ru
    [basename] => index.php
    [extension] => php
    [filename] => index
)
```

Comment: Я новичок в php. И несовсем понял что дальше нужно делать с pathinfo.

Comment: `$i  = pathinfo('blabla.ru/index.php'); echo $i['filename']; // echo index`

Comment: Вообщем условия работает. Но она работает на всех страницах сайта. Когда перехожу на др. стр.  сайта там уже эта условия не должна выполнятся а она выполняется потому как это страничка подключена c php `inсlude` и массив везде возвращает `index`  :( Как сделать чтобы на др. страницах условие не выполнялась ?

Comment: а где вы берете ссылку, которую потом парсите?

Comment: У меня локальный сервер. `eshop/index.php`